# Help with a vending trailer temporary power

Tags: trailer

temporary for 6-8 months for a vending trailer  with the wiring running around 100 feet from the pole/meter to the trailer above ground in unglued conduit can they do this in a commercial zone any one help me with this

Comment: What amperage does the trailer need?  What Voltage?  Both will affect the answer.

Comment: What type of conduit is it?

Comment: I don't know if it's thermal expansion and contraction or simply Murphy's Law at work, but it seems to me that PVC conduit has a way of working itself apart at the joints if it isn't glued.

Answer (score 0):

Only if you can convince the inspector that the wire size is sufficient to carry the expected load safely.  And secondly, you will have to convince him that the wire is absolutely protected from any physical damage that the ambient conditions can meet out.  I'm pessimistic.